# Liquibase in multiple modules on same database

Tags: database-migration, liquibase

We have two modules, app & admin, these modules are coupled, they have one database.

Is there a way to have liquibase files in both modules for same database?

Comment: Have you find solution for your problem?

Answer (score 2):

liquibase needs a table (DATABASECHANGELOG) to track changes made on the schema it manages.

You can also split your application on two differents schemas and have independant changeset management

OR

keep only one schema and manually manage your two db-changelog. In this case you have to take care to avoid same id for changeset with a prefix for example

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is completely possible. You don't specify how you are running liquibase or how your source code is arranged (or many details at all), but if you had the source for both modules in a single github repository and you were on Linux, you could just have the changelog in one place and a softlink so that the file also appeared to be in the other place. Then if you were building a standalone jar with Maven you could have the maven POM configured so that it would package the changelog into both jars. As long as the relative path was the same, whenever you trigger a database schema update from either jar, each application should compare the changelog they have to the schema of the database they are working with, look at the DATABASECHANGELOG table and come to the same conclusion as to which changesets would need to be deployed.

Comment: So, every developer need to make softlink?